# Can You Use AnkhSVN and VisualSVN at the Same Time?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visualsvn, ankhsvn

I'd like to try out a feature of AnkhSVN (namely, integration with Red Gate SQL Changeset tool) without doing an complete uninstall of VisualSVN. It feels dodgy, so I wanted to see if anyone else had experience that would either alleviate or confirm my fears.

**Update**
So I tried uninstalling VisualSVN and dropping in Ankh. As far as working within VSS itself, the change was completely transparent. Sadly, SQLChangeset did not work with this plugin, so that part of it was in vain.

Switching back was also painless, even to the point of not having to re-enter my license. So, good knowledge but no joy on the long-term goal.

Comment: @KevDog: Can you tell us about your experience with SQLChangeSet in AnkhSVN on the AnkhSVN user list? (I don't have experience with it, but maybe we can help you or other users of this changeset support)

Comment: I would be happy to, can you provide a specific link? Not sure where you would like the discussion to take place and a Google search revealed several possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort of. I've been able to *install* VisualSVN and AnkhSVN on Visual Studio at the same time. However, you won't be able to *use* both at the same time. VisualSVN is an add-in, while AnkhSVN is truly a source control plugin. To use one or the other, you simply have to disable source control binding (for AnkhSVN) or disable the plugin (for VisualSVN).

In my experience, though, I've found that VisualSVN was a much better client than AnkhSVN. VisualSVN handles ignoring user files (*.suo) and adding projects to Subversion very efficiently. AnkhSVN on the other hand, caused me some difficulty.

Hope this helps!

Comment: **VisualSVN is an add-in, while AnkhSVN is truly a source control plugin** is incorrect statement! VisualSVN has always been a low-level source-control extension, while AnkhSVN uses high-level API of Visual Studio which is quite limited.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but I know Visual Studio supports multiple source control plugins.  You just pick which one is active from the options by choosing `Tools->Options` from the menu and then finding the `Source Control->Plug-in Selection` page in the tree control on the left side of the window that opens.

It should just be a matter of installing Ankh and selecting it there for your tests, then setting back to VisualSVN when done.  Of course, that assumes everything plays nice together.

Comment: I was sort of thinking the same thing, Joel; except VisualSVN isn't a SCCI compliant (a term I only learned today) source control plug in and as such doesn't show up in the list. But I figure that uninstalling AnkhSVN is the fall back position if things go blooey.

Comment: If it's non-compliant, you might try doing your test in a VM.  I wouldn't trust something not to break if you tried to have both active at once.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to turn off / disable VisualSvn in Tools -> Addin Manager, and then select AnkhSvn as the current SCC Provider.

Can you describe how this changeset tool works, and how that should integrate with AnkhSvn?

Comment: The tool comes with SQLToolbelt, I'm not sure if they are selling it separately or if it comes bundled with SQLCompare. You use SQLCompare to generate a DB script and SQLChangeset tracks that and adds it to your VCS repository. TFS is supported out of the box, but other solutions require a compliant plug-in.

Comment: Any idea what it takes to be a compliant plug-in? Do they expect an Scc Provider, or do they talk to the (old) MSSCCI api?

Comment: I believe the hook is the MSSCCI api. I think that TFS uses this API also.