# How can I use SCM on linked files in VS2008 projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visualsvn, ankhsvn, svn-externals

**Background:**

I'm using Visual-SVN V. 1.7.5 with VS2008.  I'm fairly new to SVN.

I have a Solution that uses source files that will be shared with other Solutions.

I've put these files in a folder called "Shared", and added them to my Solution using

"Add -> Existing Item... -> Add As Link"

which works fine as far as VS2008 is concerned.

But when I try to add the linked files to SVN using the "Add to Suversion" menu item on the file's context menu, I get a warning:

"...not added to Subversion because it is out of working copy. Please setup working copy root using Visual SVN -> Set Working Copy Root menu".

I tried this, but this seems to change the root directory of the whole solution - not what I want to do.

Googling and searching SO indicates that I may want to set up some SVN Externals.  I tried to follow the examples, using the command line for the first time with Visual-SVN.  But I just got a bunch of error messages I didn't understand.

**Questions:**

1. Are Externals the way to go here?
2. If so, can someone provide some detailed, step-by-step help on how to do this with Visual-SVN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all else fails, switch to AnkhSVN, it handles them correctly.

Comment: If I try it and don't like it, will I be able to switch back to Visual-SVN with no problems?

Comment: It's just another SVN front-end, so I guess you can uninstall it and reinstall VisualSVN. Perhaps you won't even need to uninstall VisualSVN, but you can just install Ankh and select it as the current plugin.

Comment: Have not tried Ankh yet, but found another SO question that indicates switching back to VisualSVN is painless - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912103/can-you-use-ankhsvn-and-visualsvn-at-the-same-time

Comment: Finally got a chance to try Ankh.  It automatically identified all my solution's linked files, and I can now use SVN on them just like those owned by the solution. So far, seems to be as good a VisualSVN, at least for ease of use and feature set.